# wpf rotatetransform -- How do I get my control position back to normal?

Tags: wpf, offset, rotatetransform, rendertransform

Basically, I rotated an item:

```
<Button Content="HelloWorld">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

How do I get it so that it moves down. Right now it sticks straight up since I rotated it around the 0,0 point. I need it so that the 0,0 point moves down so that the top is where the original top was.

Comment: You can change the center of rotation so that it's about (0,0.5).  On a side note, you might consider using a LayoutTransform, as that way the rotated button will integrate nicely with the rest of the controls participating in layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a TranslateTransform:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="HelloWorld">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
            <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyButton}" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```